# Create CGpath from UIimageview with rotation and scale for use as cglayer mask

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, calayer, cgpath

I am still pretty new to iOS, though I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

I have 2 separate UIImageView's

1. The 'Background'. This is a picture that is going to have a layer mask applied to it so that you can only see part of the image.
2. The 'Mask Image' this is it's own independent image that can be rotated, panned, pinch zoomed. The code for rotate/scale works fine and is standard code.

What I am trying to do is create a CGPath that matches the current location/rotation/scale of the 'Mask Image'

Here is my code for grabbing the location of the 'Mask Image' and creating a CGPAth to use as a layer mask.

If you go to Xcode and make a new 'Single View Application' project, here is the full copy paste of the ViewController

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *makskedImageView;
    UIImageView *maskImageView;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage *sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"forest.jpg"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (sourceImage.size.width/2), (sourceImage.size.height/2))];
    imageView.image = sourceImage;

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    makskedImageView = imageView;

    //    Movable Mask
    UIImage *frameBorder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"semiTransSquare.png"];
    maskImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (frameBorder.size.width/2), (frameBorder.size.height/2))];
    maskImageView.image = frameBorder;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [panGesture2 setDelegate:self];
    [maskImageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture2];
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture2 = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    [pinchGesture2 setDelegate:self];
    [maskImageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture2];
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateGesture2 = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotate:)];
    [rotateGesture2 setDelegate:self];
    [maskImageView addGestureRecognizer:rotateGesture2];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [tapGR setDelegate:self];
    [tapGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [maskImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];

    [maskImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    // Add to view to make visible;
    [self.view addSubview:maskImageView];

    // apply layer mask to makskedImageView
    [self grabTransform:maskImageView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)grabTransform:(UIView *)currentView
{
    // build the transform you want
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[currentView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
    CGFloat scale = [(NSNumber *)[currentView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.scale"] floatValue];
    t = CGAffineTransformConcat(t, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale));
    t = CGAffineTransformConcat(t, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle));
    NSLog(@"angle: %f, scale: %f", angle, scale);

    // Create a mask layer
    // Create a mask layer and the frame to determine what will be visible in the view.
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    // CGRect maskRect = currentView.bounds;
    // Frame works a lot better.
    CGRect maskRect = currentView.frame;

    maskRect.origin.x = currentView.frame.origin.x;
    maskRect.origin.y = currentView.frame.origin.y;

    // Make a Path friendly transform.

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentView.frame), CGRectGetMidY(currentView.frame));
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);

    // Create a path and from the rectangle in it.
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, &transform);
    // Set the path to the mask layer.
    [maskLayer setPath:path];
    // Release the path since it's not covered by ARC.
    CGPathRelease(path);
    // Set the mask of the view.
    makskedImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;


}

#pragma mark - Gestures

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
    [self grabTransform:[recognizer view]];
}

-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);

    recognizer.scale = 1;
    [self grabTransform:[recognizer view]];
}

-(void)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;
valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation"] floatValue];
    [self grabTransform:[recognizer view]];
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [self grabTransform:[recognizer view]];

}

@end
```

Plus 2 Images: [Forest.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5b1P.jpg) & [semiTransSquare.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgcus.png)

Now when this runs it works for panning until I scale.rotate the image. (rotate working now thanks to some other code).

From what I can tell scale works with the Center as the point around which it grows/shrinks, where the path seems to scale out from the root x,y co-ordinates.

This might be by design ([CGPathCreateWithRect per the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateWithRect)) but I can't see a way to apply the transforms to the CGPath and have it appear in the same place as the UIImageView 'Mask Image'

Performance is a big issue and a similar solution with CIImage was very laggy so would like to solve this in the context of having CGPath create the layer mask if that is possible, or something that is just as fast.

What am I missing? Happy for iOS 6 only solutions.

**Update:** I found that changing from bounds to frame gets me 90% of the way there:

```
CGRect maskRect = currentView.frame;
```

The path will now match the rotation and position of the view. The only issue remaining is that the scale is wrong. It matches at the original size, but if you shrink then it gets too small or if you grow it gets too big. Looks like the scale isn't 1:1. So close now.

Comment: Added in a bounty. I feel this can't be that hard. :-) Let me know if I need to create a dummy app with full code to show the issue more clearly.

Comment: If you add a dummy app, I'll have a close look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your description of the problem, so a dummy app would be really helpful. But here's my analysis from what I can seen now:

You say that you have two UIImageViews, Background and MaskImage. From this, and from your code, I understand that what you want to do is:

1. get a CGPath that represents the actual shape of MaskImage, after various transforms have been applied, from the point of view of (presumably) a superview or some higher-than-superview.
2. Use that CGPath to define a CAShapeLayer, which you will use as the mask on the backing layer of some other view, presumably the Background UIImageView

In that case, MaskImage in your text corresponds to your code's `currentView` (since that's where you're getting the transform), and Background in your text corresponds to your code's `currentImageView` (since that's where you're changing the layer's mask). Right?

If all of that is correct, then there are two key problems with your code:

1. You want to get the a CGPath representing the *transformed shape* of currentView. But you're grabbing `currentView.frame`. This is wrong. `currentView.frame` will represent the smallest rect, in the coordinates of `currentView.superview`, which can contain the transformed shape of currentView. So, for instance, if currentView is a square rotated by 45 degrees, then currentView.frame is still a square, just a larger square. Instead, what you should be doing is getting `currentView.bounds`, which is the rect that represents how currentView's shape in its own coordinate system, generating a path from that, and then apply `currentView.transform` to that path.
2. You don't specify anywhere, in your code or text, how to map from the coordinate system of `currentView.superview` to the coordinate system of MaskImage. You also need to do this before applying the shape to MaskImage.layer.mask.

For instance, I can imagine an application where the screen was cut into two equal side left and right, which presented a large photo image on the left side of the screen, and on the right side of the screen it allowed you to pan, rotate, and scale an image of a black rectangle. Then the app would use the black rectangle on the right-hand side to define a CAShapeLayer that was applied as a mask over the image on the left-hand side. This sounds like what you're going for. So what I'm saying is, that the logical set of steps you need for this to work is:

1. Get a CGPath for the *bounds* of the black rect, which will be an untransfored rect.
2. Transform this CGPath with the same transform being applied on the black rectangle.
3. Represent this CGPath in the coordinate system of a rect containing just the right-hand side of the screen. Since the right-hand and left-hand sides are congruent, it is now also in the coordinate system that can be directly applied to the left-hand side of the screen.
4. Use the CGPath to define a CALayer, apply this CALayer to the view representing the left-hand side of the screen, and call setNeedsDisplay on that view's layer.

P.S. By the way, there's a third problem. Note that, technically, when you add a .mask to a layer, that layer should not have a superlayer. So you shouldn't add a .mask to the backing layer of a UIView already in the view hierarchy, since it will have a super layer.So, I believe, what you should do is temporarily remove the UIView from the view hierarchy, add the mask layer, and then re-add the view to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added in the full example code (with images). Using bounds helped but it still goes to pieces when I rotate or scale but its a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the function

> `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath`?

It takes a `CGRect` and an affine transform which should achieve what you are after.

FYI it's iOS 5 +

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that didn't work. I tried using the t variable or the transform variable applied to the maskrect variable from my code example above and it still does the same thing. If you did get it to work using the sample code, please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the valid scale factor using:

```
CGFloat zoomScale = sqrtf( powf(currentView.transform.a, 2) + powf(currentView.transform.c, 2) );
```

Which is not equal to:

```
CGFloat scale = [(NSNumber *)[currentView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.scale"] floatValue];
```